# MSSQL 2019 Installation Problem How to solve Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oledb

While trying to install MSSQL 2019 ON Windows-10 I got a problem.

I was almost done with the installation when this pops up:

[image: oleodbc-error]

If I skip it, I won't be able to access the MSSQL Server..

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Try a new installation media, looks like a corrupted file/installation media, all these drivers should be part of the installation media.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download and install package *Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server* from [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/download-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). It resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to ask whether you have restarted after following the prompts? Is there anything different?
If there is still an error, please go to the control panel -> uninstall program page to see if there is Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server
If it exists, please uninstall it and restart your machine. Then reinstall sql server.
If the installation still fails, please see this document and manually install the Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server then install sql server.
Hope you can succeed, if you have any questions, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: You say, "please see this document", but you didn't include a document. Did you meant to include a link?

Answer (score 0):

You have to download [Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server version 18.6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/release-notes-for-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#previous-releases), only version of 18.6.0 will be OK, and keep the file name to be msoledbsql.msi.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the previous version of Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server from the Control Panel | Programs and retry the original install.